# Pause Telnet shell to enter a new command

Tags: windows, shell, telnet

I am trying to issue commands to telnet. When I initially issue a simple connection command such as:

```
telnet localhost 9300
```

I am immediately connected which is fantastic but there are messages that instantly start printing in the shell every 1 second. These are expected responses from the program connected to that port. The issue is, how do I issue a second command when the shell won't stop logging data? I can't type in the shell when it is moving. Thanks for any help and sorry for the newbie type question.

Answer (score 0):

You can type blind, just ignore that your line disappears in the stdout of telnet.
With copy-paste from a buffer, you can see your line, but it will still move out of the screen.

Another way is redirecting the output of telnet to a file.
When you want to see the telnet output, open a second window.
Window 1:

```
telnet localhost 9300 > telnet9300.out 2>&1
enter your commands here
```

Window 2:

```
# wait for telnet9300.out being created
tail -f telnet9300.out
# Press ^C when you have seen enough
```